# Laravel 4 - get returns all entities

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have had an issue occur multiple times within my Laravel project.  Basically, I create an object using the Model::create() function.  Then, when I return the model as JSON, I use Laravel's eager loading function to return the model.  I use the following line(s) to return the model:

```
$event = Social_Event::create(array(
    'creator_id' => Auth::user()->id
) + Input::all());

return Response::json(array(
    'event' => $event
));
```

With that, I get a JSON encoded list of every existing conversation.  I have never had that issue before.  Does anyone see a cause for it?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's a missing parenthesis there.

Comment: There is a missing parenthesis in the return and also why are you adding the user_id with the input? Is the `Input::all()` an integer?

Comment: I didnt copy and paste that code right from my text editor(I always have trouble with pasted code), so that's why the parenthesis is missing, and Input::all() is an array of input(POST) variables

Comment: @rossEdman He's using the plus as an array union operator. array() + the return value of Input::all(), which is also an array. http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php

Comment: Did you inspect the `array` you are passing to `create` and `$event` using `dd()` or similar? If so, it would be helpful to know what was the outcome.